# Moving Office puzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

**Moving Office**

You are moving office. You would like to be behind Elisabeth. But Elisabeth wants to be behind you.

Is there a solution ?

I tried for some time and to me it seems answer is going to be no but I am not sure.

**Reference :**  https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fgandon/miscellaneous/riddle/ (see puzzle number 15)

Comment: What's the source of this puzzle?

Comment: Are you aware that that site has links to the answers on the right?

Comment: Just introduce flex spots where both can be behind eachother on seperate days :D

Comment: As @Chris has stated, the link you posted also gives the answer to the right of the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's possible:

> Place your desks back to back.

Answer (score 4):

> Move into one of [Mobius' office](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_strip)s. Mind you, a simple looped office would work as well.

Answer (score 3):

There is a virtual solution!

> Seat Elisabeth and you opposite to each other (that means you face each other). Then have a full-size mirrors arranged at the back of each of you, such that the reflecting surfaces face each other and are parallel, which gives more than the number of seat arrangement required by you !! :-)

Answer (score -1):

Yes if they are back to back..!!

Comment: This is the same as [another answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/53869/9000) posted 6 hours earlier. If you have more to add to the solution, please do so. Otherwise, consider upvoting or commenting on the other answer instead of posting a duplicate.